# is it possible to prevent duplicate entry in the multiline textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

what I'm trying to do is I want to try prevent duplicate entry from the multiline textbox . From what I know for Multiline , all of them is in one string. You can search but you cannot remove a line. Or is there any possible method to remove duplicate entry in a multiline textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preventing duplicate input in the first place is not really practical. Removing duplicate input is easy:

```
myTextBox.Lines = myTextBox.Lines.Distinct().ToArray()
```

Oops, just realised this is ASP.NET.  You could still do this:

```
myTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                             myTextBox.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct())
```

You'd have to postback to do that though.  Maybe you want to do it in client-side script, although you didn't say so.

Comment: I've tried it, it just doesn't work for me.Thank for the response tho. But how is it to apply to a client side script?

Comment: It works if you do it properly, so you didn't do it properly. As fore doing it client-side, if that is the question you want answered then put it in the question, not in a comment on an answer. Also, add appropriate tags to your question to indicate that this is actually a scripting question and not a VBV.NET question.

Comment: okay I've tried it again and it works. I just placed it wrongly at the previous try. Thank you for the help